# Matar sessão ORACLE 12c

Tags: session, oracle12c

bom dia.
Gostaria de rodar um comando para matar sessões no ORACLE 12C porém o unico comando que conheço é o ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid, serial, @instancia' IMMEDIATE;

Porém eu queria matar as sessões específicas sem digitar o SID e SERIAL sempre, ex:

WHERE machine LIKE 'BOA\BOASRV120'
AND username LIKE 'CONSINCO'
AND PROGRAM = 'w3wp.exe'

Matar todas as sessões que se enquadram nesse WHERE acima.

Essa sessões ficam com status INACTIVE e queria mata-las para ficarem como 'KILLED';

Há alguma forma?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode construir um bloco anônimo que basicamente busca suas sessões, monta o comando e executa.
Veja:

```
BEGIN     
 FOR reg in (SELECT 'alter system kill session ''' || ses.sid || ',' || ses.serial# ||''''  cmd
               FROM v$session ses
              WHERE machine LIKE 'BOA\BOASRV120'
                AND username LIKE 'CONSINCO'
                AND program = 'w3wp.exe') LOOP                
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE reg.cmd;     
 END LOOP; 
END;
```

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou demais - Rodei ele na mão , filtrando 01 sessão só e matou!  Para eu transformar esse código em uma Procedure só preciso rodar o comando "Create or Replace Procedure "nome_tal" as (código) ou eu preciso passar alum parametro para funcionar quando eu chamar ela com call ou exec?
Quero colocar ela num editor Query View, para o usuário só clicar num botão e matar os usuários travados, assim ele nem tem acesso a código nem nada.

Comment: Pode transformar sim. Não precisa de parâmetros, a menos que de fato queria parametrizar alguma coisa na busca das sessões...  Se a resposta te ajudou é o caso [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/)